# Does closure property work in reverse? That is, if $a + b$ belongs to a set closed under addition, are $a$ and $b$ members of that set?

Tags: proof-writing, field-theory

If a set is closed under addition, and a number $a + b$ belongs to that set, does it follow that $a$ and $b$ are members of that set?

Comment: $(1-\frac{1}{2}) + \frac{1}{2}=1 \in \mathbb Z$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No: the even numbers are closed under addition and $1 + 1$ is even, but $1$ is not even.

Comment: Maybe even simpler: $\{0\}$ is closed under addition . . .

Comment: @bof: thanks for pointing out that slip. I've deleted my silly comment.